# Running python script with a parameter using cronjob gives error: /bin/sh: password: command not found

Tags: python, linux, cron

I'm going to run a python script with a parameter using cronjob.
The parameter is password of database that needs to be used in the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb
import requests
import json
import os
import sys
param=sys.argv
password=param[1]

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="host.com",port=3306,user="user",passwd=password,db="db")
```

/etc/crontab:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
```

Crontab -e

```
*/5 * * * *  /home/test/run.py "dbpass'"
```

which python:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Error in /var/spool/mail

```
/bin/sh: dbpass': command not found
```

If I run the script manually, it works fine:  python run.py "dbpass'"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error says that cron tries to use "dbpass" as the command. Are you sure this is in a user crontab and not in the system wide (/etc/crontab) which expects an user name as the 6th field?

Comment: @mata Hi, thanks for the command. Yes, I put it in crontab -e without username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you posted contains unicode characters, it's representation is

```
u'*/5 * * * *\u2002\u2002/home/test/run.py "dbpass\'"'
# or encoded to utf-8:
b'*/5 * * * *\xe2\x80\x82\xe2\x80\x82/home/test/run.py "dbpass\'"'
```

`\u2002` is EN SPACE

So the 5th argument is actually `*\u2002\u2002/home/test/run.py` which it seems cron treats like a `*`, taking the next item as the command.

So just replace those EN SPACE characters with normal spaces then it should work.

Comment: Sorry, the comment `# or in bytes` is inexact:  It might say, `# or in utf-8`.  The former being the plain utf representation (or the equivalent for non special characters utf-16)

Answer (score -1):

Your crontab entry should have the password without quotes:

```
*/5 * * * *  /home/test/run.py dbpass
```

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. I need the "" around the dbpass because of MySQLdb.connect() format. Then how I fix it there?

Comment: You don't need any additional quotes in `MySQLdb.connect()` - the password read from CLI arguments will already be a string.

Comment: The quotes from the crontab will not be passed as argument, they are removed by the shell, so it's perfectly fine to have them there.